# К какой структуре данных относится список?

Tags: python, массивы, список, структуры-данных

Списки в Python, какая это структура данных — массив или список?

Comment: В питоне насколько мне известно - нет массивов как таковых, только списки. https://all-python.ru/osnovy/massivy.html

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, да ну? :) https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/array.html?highlight=array

Comment: Согласен, был не прав =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На самом деле вопрос хороший, т.к. реализация списка может быть через список (хранение node и ссылок между ними) или через динамический массив. А от этого может зависеть поведение кода при работе с этой структурой.

Список реализуется через массив: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented-in-cpython

А согласно этому [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented/3958322#3958322) можно [посмотреть реализацию списка в стандартной реализации интерпретатора](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c22476c01622f11b7745ee693f8b296a9d6a761/Include/listobject.h#L22):

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    Py_ssize_t ob_size;

    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    /* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
     * currently in use is ob_size.
     * Invariants:
     *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
     *     len(list) == ob_size
     *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
     */
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

Как видно, это реализация через массив.

---

**PS.**

Согласно, [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917591/5909792), следующие реализации интерпретатора используют массив как реализацию списка:

- CPython [использует массив](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c22476c01622f11b7745ee693f8b296a9d6a761/Include/listobject.h#L22)
- Jython использует массив через реализацию списка [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- IronPython [тоже использует массив](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/blob/c43b3b50e4f9379c755c087ff7523da64c0ba3e0/Src/IronPython/Runtime/List.cs#L34).