# В чем отличие массива от списка в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list

Существует ли в языке Python такая структура данных, как массив? Имеется в виду классический массив. Или только списки? Если я не ошибаюсь, список - это своего рода "обертка" над классическим массивом. Поправьте, если я не прав.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Да, питоновый список (list) это и есть классический массив, вот такая запутанная терминология

Comment: По классике массив содержит элементы одного типа. Списку же на типы пофиг. Так что если у тебя все элементы списка однотипны, можешь для себя назвать этот список массивом.

Comment: @Akina этим «одним типом» вполне может быть абстрактный Object, который в рантайме можно скастовать во что нужно. Вроде даже в Си так можно, если извратиться с struct/union и указателями

Comment: @andreymal Ну так можно сказать, что это будет массив указателей. А на что они там указывают - дело десятое, массив так далеко не смотрит... адрес, и ладно.

Comment: @Akina ну технически список в питоне это как раз массив указателей, ага)

Comment: По сути, списки используются в питоне вместо массивов, они могу исполнять все функции массива. Также есть модуль array, который позволяет немного проще работать с массивами в питоне, об этом можете почитать здесь 
https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-array-massivy-v-python.html

Comment: Кст, сам `list` внутри себя через массив реализован: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1019553/201445