# Списки и массивы в Python

Tags: python

Недавно прочитал книгу "Грокаем Алгортмы", и там сравнивались массивы и списки. Вопрос, в Python можно создавать и списки и массивы? Или только списки?

Comment: "можно создавать и списки и массивы" можно и списки, и массивы. Для массивов нужно отдельный модуль использовать, а списки доступны по умолчанию -- `list` или `[]`. Если интересно как внутри списки питона реализованы, то: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1019553/201445

Comment: @gil9red и вы тоже путаете python-список и связный список?)

Comment: Массивы (довольно оптимизированные) есть в популярной библиотеке numpy. В самом питоне - только списки и наборы.

Answer (score 4):

В Python можно создать и связный список и массив:

- массивы доступны "из коробки" в классе `list` (да, название переводится как список, но на самом деле это именно массив [пруф](https://www.quora.com/How-are-Python-lists-implemented-internally)), также можно использовать различные вариации из библиотеки `numpy`, например `numpy.array`, `numpy` поддерживает многомерные массивы
- связный список это достаточно простая структура данных которую, например, можно быстро реализовать самостоятельно средствами языка

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append(self, data):
        if not self.tail:
            self.head = Node(data)
            self.tail = head
        else:
            self.tail.next = Node(data)
            self.tail = self.tail.next
```

и так далее; другие варианты можно искать по запросу `linked list in python`

Answer (score 0):

В базовом Python доступны списки.
Модуль  array  позволяет работать с массивами. Но не слишком эффективно.
Модуль numpy дает полную свободу при работе с в том числе многомерными массивами.