# Вопрос к тем, кто читал книгу A byte of python

Tags: python

Итак, я совсем новичок в программировании, и решил начать с питона (ЭТО МОЙ ВЫБОР КРИТИКА ПО ОТНОШЕНИЮ К ВЫБОРУ НЕ ПРИВЕТСТВУЕТСЯ!). Вопрос такой, я знаю что такое массивы, но не знаю что такое списки, так вот в этой книгу (A byte of python) нет ничего про массивы, есть про какие-то списки, может ли быть так, что книгу написали без главы массивов, или списки это и есть массивы, но с другим названием?

Comment: Считайте, что это одно и то же (если речь идёт о `list`). Возможный дубликат вопроса: [К какой структуре данных относится список?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1019550/%d0%9a-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 0):

Согласно документации Python:

> Internally, a list is represented as an array; the largest costs come from growing beyond the current allocation size (because everything must move), or from inserting or deleting somewhere near the beginning (because everything after that must move).

То есть list в Python представляет собой массив.