# В чем различие обычных и связанных списков?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Я уже достаточно много изучаю питон и при чтении книги "Грокаем алгоритмы" встретился с термином связанные списки и массивы. Сначала я подумал что первое это тоже самое что и список, а вот про массивы я загуглил, пройдя некоторое время я увидел гайд как создать связанный список. На этом моменте я сильно запутался, я долго сидел гуглил, но никакой информации об их различиях не нашел. А сейчас я сижу и не понимаю вообще что такое список, является ли он структурой данных. Объясните пожалуйста что же такое список и является ли он чем то отличным от связанного списка?
я честно пытался самостоятельно разобраться...(

Comment: Список в Python это на самом деле массив (как структура данных). В информатике в целом под списками обычно имеются в виду связные списки.

Comment: @insolor hahahah, вы безукоризненно правы, но мне кажется только больше запутали автора вопроса

Comment: если обычный список который мы создаем [ ] скобками, это и есть массив, то почему в него можно добавлять объекты любого класса?

Comment: @宏zxcgod宏︎ потому что объект любого класса является подтипом object. На низком уровне любой объект Python описывается по сути одной и той же структурой на языке Си.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [К какой структуре данных относится список?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1019550/1365)

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato согласен, от того что  массив это список, а список это связанный список, стало еще непонятней x_x

Comment: @宏zxcgod宏︎ есть разница между типами данных в языках программирования и структурами данных, которыми они реализуются. В случае Python тип данных list реализуется через структуру данных массив.

Answer (score 2):

Разница в том что это разные структуры данных для разных целей, основные отличия можно уместить в несколько предложений.

Массив, в отличие от списка используется для обращения к определенному участку памяти, а так же может хранить данные только одного типа, тогда как связный список может хранить несколько типов данных, из-за этого время на поиск нужного элемента массива затрачивается меньше `O(1)`, тогда как перебор элементов связного списка занимает `O(N)`.

Как понять что в Вашем коде нужно использовать, массив или же список?

Можно привести один явный пример, когда Вам нужно проводить операции например с очень большой матрицей, условно 100х100, то массивы являются незаменимой вещью, по причине которую я описывал выше (Затрата времени на поиск нужного элемента `O(1)`)

Но когда у вас есть небольшой определенный список данных с разными элементами, то вместо того что бы использовать несколько массивов с разными типами данных, будет просто все реализовать в 1 списке

Так же стоит упомянуть то что модуль массива перед началом работы нужно импортировать, тогда как список - нет

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135191/discussion-on-answer-by----ii------).

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается, а для меня это новость, что бы действительно использовать в `python` массивы нам потребуется библиотека -  `from array import *`

Пример объявления реального массива:

```
my_array = array('i',[1,2,3,4])
```